# set cookie expires date to today js

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to set cookie expires date to now or to pass date.
this because i have on my site a box with a lot of links that stored in cookie,
when the user press 'X' next to a link this place in the array needs to be deleted. 
here is some code

```js
function get_favorites_cookie(){
    var aaa = Cookies.get('aaa');
    return aaa;
}

function update_favorites_cookie( id, delete_item ){

    var bbb = get_favorites_cookie();

    if( ! favorites_cookie ) {
        Cookies.set('aaa', id, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    } else {

        if( ! delete_item ){
            Cookies.set('aaa', bbb + '+' + id, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
        } else {
            var array = favorites_cookie.split('+');
            console.log(array);
            var index = array.indexOf( id );
            array.splice(index, 1);
            // update array + update cookie
            
            Cookies.set('fav_cookie', favorites_cookie + '+' + id, { expires: date.toGMTString(), path: '/' });
        }
    }

}
```

thanks

Comment: setting expires  to a negative value will remove your cookie. Are you looking to remove your cookie?

Comment: i have an array of ids inside one cookie and im looking to remove one of the ids on click

Comment: and after deleting that 1 item, you want to set the cookie expiration to?

Comment: no, im tring to delete it and i assumed it was by setting the expiration date for today. if theres a better way i will gld to hear

Answer (score 0):

found the answer!
i just needed to loop trough all ids in my cookie and push to another aaray all selected cookie, reset the cookie and pass the new array